# Does a javascript animate need to be set for different browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I have a small jQuery function that makes the browser window slide down when the user clicks on an item, but it behaves differently in different browsers.

This is the html:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li class="navBack hvr-grow" data-target="section.bg.s-h">about</li>
<li class="navServe hvr-grow" data-target="section.services.s-h">services</li>
<li class="navContact hvr-grow" data-target="section.contact.s-h">contact</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

And the JS:

```
$("nav ul li").click(function(){
$('html,body').animate({"scrollTop": "515"}),3000
});
```

Is there some way to set a webkit type thing so that this will work the same way in all browsers?

Comment: Is it different in all major browsers or just IE?

Comment: Should be cross browser compatible.  That is what jquery is all about

Comment: I think it was good in Firefox but Chrome was doing the same thing as IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in you code you must replace your js with:

```
$("nav ul li").click(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({"scrollTop": "515"},3000);
});
```

Comment: That looks correct but it's still not doing what it's supposed to. It's not actually sliding in Firefox now, it's just a sharp movement. It's still not working right in IE either, it's fine for the first and last item in the menu but the second has a different top. Could it be because there's another click function on the same element?

Comment: And for those of us who don't want to compare your code with the OP's character by character what actually is the syntax error?

Comment: I know what's causing it now. The site displays differently in the browsers. IE makes the text smaller and there's not enough content on that second menu item to make the page scroll to where it's supposed to. For some reason the scroll is now working in Firefox too. I'll have to think about ways to fix that second menu item now. I'm thinking CSS.